# Not able to mass transfer records based on the condition

Tags: javascript, ajax-toolkit, list-button, sforce.connection

I need to have a list button used to assign the records to the corresponding queue based on the lead type. Here is my code . I dont know that part i have missed here.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/16.0/connection.js")} 
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead)};
var url = parent.location.href;
var newRecords = [];
var leadObj = new sforce.SObject("Lead");
if(records[0] ==null) 
alert('Please select a record');
if(records.length>0) {
for(i=0;i<records.length;i++) {
    leadObj.Id = records[i];
    if(leadObj.TypeOfInterest__c =='VO'&& leadObj.Country__c =='France') {
            leadObj.OwnerId = '00G7E000000rZIs'; // Queue Id 
    }
    else if(leadObj.TypeOfInterest__c =='VN'&& leadObj.Country__c =='France') {
            leadObj.OwnerId = '00G7E000000rZIr'; // Queue Id
    }
    newRecords.push(leadObj);
}
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
parent.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: is only one lead is getting updated?

Comment: Is this question still open?

Answer (score 0):

**Notes**

- You must re-instantiate `leadObj` for each record.
- You should really query for your `Queue` ids.
- You can use the `window.reload()` function, no need to store current url.
- You are using an *ancient* API Version. Update it from `16.0` to `37.0`.

  - You actually can't query a `Group` based on `DeveloperName` without bumping it up to at least `24.0`.
- JSLint would advise you to consolidate your `var` statements, for whatever that's worth.

**Working Button Code**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")} 
var leadObj, q1Id, q2Id, newRecords = [], records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead)};

if(records.length == 0) {
    alert('Please select a record');
}
else{
    q1Id = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Queue' AND DeveloperName = 'First_Queue_Name'").records.Id;
    q2Id = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Queue' AND DeveloperName = 'Second_Queue_Name'").records.Id;
    for(i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        leadObj = new sforce.SObject("Lead");
        leadObj.Id = records[i];
        if(/*some criteria*/) {
                leadObj.OwnerId = q1Id;
        }
        else if(/*some other criteria*/) {
                leadObj.OwnerId = q2Id;
        }
        newRecords.push(leadObj);
    }
    result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
    parent.location.reload();
}
```