# Mass transfer not happening while using custom list button

Tags: javascript, list-button

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/16.0/connection.js")} 
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead)};
var url = parent.location.href;
var newRecords = [];
if(records[0] ==null) 
alert('Please select a record');
if(records.length>0) {
for(i=0;i<records.length;i++) {
    var leadObj = new sforce.SObject("Lead");
    leadObj.Id = records[i];
    if(leadObj.TypeOfInterest__c =='VO'&& leadObj.Country__c =='France') {

            leadObj.OwnerId = '00G7E000000rZIs';
    }
    else if(leadObj.TypeOfInterest__c =='VN'&& leadObj.Country__c =='France') {
            leadObj.OwnerId = '00G7E000000rZIr';
    }
    newRecords.push(leadObj);
}
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
parent.location.href = url;
}
```

Using the above code , mass transfer is not happening. PLease tell me what is missing here? It is not entering into the if loop. it is directly going to sforce update.

Comment: possible duplicate http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/130859/20830

Comment: yes that question was asked by me from another system. So please ignore that :)

Comment: then you should delete that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `{!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead)}` only the Lead Ids is returned as Array.You need to query Lead object using the collected ids, to get the respective leads fields: `Country__c`,`TypeOfInterest__c`.

Doc to the sforce examples can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm).

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/16.0/connection.js")} 
var leadIds = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead)},
    url = parent.location.href,
    newRecords = [],leadIdStr,result;

if(typeof leadIds[0] == 'undefined'){
    alert('Please select a record');
} 

for(var i = 0;i < leadIds.length;i++) {
    if(leadIdStr){
        leadIdStr += ','+'\''+leadIds[i]+'\'';
    }
    else{
        leadIdStr = '\''+leadIds[i]+'\'';
    }
}


if(leadIdStr){
    var leads = sforce.connection.query("Select Id,TypeOfInterest__c,Country__c FROM Lead WHERE Id IN ("+leadIdStr+")"),
        leaseRecords = leads.getArray("records");

    for (var i = 0; i < leaseRecords.length; i++) {

        var leadObj = new sforce.SObject("Lead");
        leadObj.Id = leaseRecords[i].Id;

        leadObj.OwnerId = '00G280000029OrK'; // Queue Id 


        newRecords.push(leadObj);
    }

    result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
    parent.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot praveen . It worked :)